# Large Excel File From SSRS Sorting

Tags: excel, reporting-services

A SSRS 2005 report that is run by multiple users is generating about 45,000+ records and then being exported to Excel.  This is working fine, but when the users try to sort/filter the results they are seeing a huge amount of lag.  At first I thought that it was just because of the large number of rows, but we found that when we stripped all of the formatting from the Excel file the report sorted and filtered quickly.  Is this a common problem any of you have seen and how would you resolve it?  They need the formatting to stay on the main report, so if I could somehow export without formatting that would be ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: An interesting thing to note, is that if you open the Excel file (normally an XLS in 97-2003 format) and save it again (in the same format) without changing anything, the file will be smaller. Apparently, SSRS is adding some stuff. I don't know what, why or how much, but maybe it could make your Excel file small enough? Obviously, this isn't a real solution, that's why I put it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are only three settings you can set for the ReportViewer excel renderer.
See [Excel Device Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155069.aspx)

Unfortunately, none of which will omit formatting in your exported report.
The only thing I can suggest is that you strip out all the formatting from the RDLC report file, prior to exporting.